# Throw native JS exception in Scala.js

Tags: exception, error-handling, scala.js

Scala's `throw` expects a Throwable, which `js.Error` is not.

I need to re-throw a JS error that was provided to me by a third party JS lib. Said lib will then catch that re-thrown error again and do something about it.

I could write a one-line npm module in JS: `module.exports = function (e) { throw e; }`, and add it to my `npmDependencies`, but I was wondering if there is a better solution for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to wrap the JS error in a `js.JavaScriptException`:

```
import scala.scalajs.js

throw js.JavaScriptException(e)
```

Comment: Thanks, somehow I missed this. I see that Scala.js calls `unwrapJavaScriptException` before `throw`-ing such an exception, so the original JS error will be re-thrown, which is just what I need. I should read more Scala.js sources...